# Компиляция програм под 32 битную систему из 64 битной

Tags: rust

Как в rust-e на windows 64 bit скомпилировать программу для windows 32 bit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно поставить трипл:

`rustup target add i686-pc-windows-gnu`

или

`rustup target add i686-pc-windows-msvc`

и потом: `cargo build --target i686-pc-windows-gnu`